how to label mean value on seaborn boxplot?
i made a code for boxplot in seaborn and I want to label mean value of the boxplot, not showmeans option, the "number".


import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib
import math



data = {
    'GROUP': ['AAA1', 'AAA1', 'AAA1', 'AAA1'],
    'NAME': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'QTY': [56, 43, 55, 59],
    'TEM0001': ['A52', 'B52', 'A22', 'A22'],
    'TEM0002': ['B52', 'C32', 'B56', 'B56'],
    'TEM0003': ['C52', 'D54', 'C32', 'C4'],
    'TEM0004': ['D54', 'E43', 'D33', 'D33'],
    'TEM0005': ['E43', 'T56', 'E44', 'E44'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

column_indices = range(3,10) 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(math.ceil( len(column_indices)/4), 4, figsize=(10,8))
axes = axes.flatten() 

for i, col_idx in enumerate(column_indices):
    df_selected = df.iloc[:, [2, col_idx]]
    bp = sns.boxplot(data=df_selected, x=df_selected.columns[1], y='QTY', hue=df_selected.columns[1], ax=axes[i])
    m1= df_selected.groupby(df_selected.columns[1])['QTY'].median().values
    
for j in range(len(column_indices), len(axes)):
    axes[j].axis('off')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

labeling mean value for each boxplot.

You can use the Axes.annotate method to add a label to your charts. All you need are the x/y positions for as to where one should put the annotation. See Matplotlib Annotation Docs for further guidance.
(in your question you specified the mean but in your code it seemed you wanted to calculate the median, so I opted for the latter.)
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib
import math



data = {
    'GROUP': ['AAA1', 'AAA1', 'AAA1', 'AAA1'],
    'NAME': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'QTY': [56, 43, 55, 59],
    'TEM0001': ['A52', 'B52', 'A22', 'A22'],
    'TEM0002': ['B52', 'C32', 'B56', 'B56'],
    'TEM0003': ['C52', 'D54', 'C32', 'C4'],
    'TEM0004': ['D54', 'E43', 'D33', 'D33'],
    'TEM0005': ['E43', 'T56', 'E44', 'E44'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

column_indices = range(3,8)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(math.ceil( len(column_indices)/4), 4, figsize=(10,8))
axes = axes.flatten()

for i, col_idx in enumerate(column_indices):
    df_selected = df.iloc[:, [2, col_idx]]
    bp = sns.boxplot(data=df_selected, x=df_selected.columns[1], y='QTY', hue=df_selected.columns[1], ax=axes[i])

    # calculate label y-positions, iterate along the x-axis and add annotations
    m1= df_selected.groupby(df_selected.columns[1])['QTY'].median()
    for x in axes[i].get_xticklabels():
        xlab = x.get_text()
        med = m1[xlab]
        axes[i].annotate(
            text=med,
            xy=(xlab, med),
            ha='center',
            va='bottom',
        )

for j in range(len(column_indices), len(axes)):
    axes[j].axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Just add the label argument (a string or list of strings), here is how:
bp = sns.boxplot(data=df_selected, x=df_selected.columns[1], y='QTY', hue=df_selected.columns[1], ax=axes[i], label="your_label")

Then add the legend method before showing the boxplots:
plt.tight_layout()
# add .legend() method 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()


No, this does not annotate the values. You clearly didn’t bother to test this.
